# Configure Azure to run nodejs app in development environment

Tags: node.js, azure

NodeJS applications on Azure portal are running by default in `production` environment (`process.env.NODE_ENV` is production).

Is it possible to change the environment to `development`? And how?

(If it matters, I configured the application as a `Web Site` on Azure.)

Comment: Are you asking [how to set an environment variable on Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/223104/setting-environment-variable-for-just-one-command-in-windows-cmd-exe)?

Comment: No. I'm asking how to configure azure to run the development environment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the NODE_ENV variable under the Website App settings configuration on the portal: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/#howtochangeconfig

Additionally, if you are using the [Azure CLI](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/) (which you can install via `npm install azure-cli -g`), you can run the following `azure site config add NODE_ENV=development` assuming your CLI is configured.

This will ask you for the website name then set the config.

Comment: doesn't the app settings in azure add the prefix to it and break how NODE would pick up that setting?

Comment: I saw this when I first started this adventure. I just chuckled to myself and said, yea, I bet that works great for a dotnet app. No way in hell that's ever going to work with node since it's Microsoft. A couple weeks later after trying multiple different setups I came back to this. It works like a charm. I just put in an app setting and referenced it in my node app (`process.env.*`) and it worked like a champ. I hate to do it, but one gold star for microsft. I definitely thought they were just running node in some bastardized fashion with no access to anything you would actually need.